# LINQ orderby/display parent elements by subcollection specific names

Tags: c#, linq

This is i have the object

```
[{State: "TX",
Type: {"Secondary", "Third"}},
{State: "PA",
Type: {"Primary","Secondary"}}
{State: "NC",
Type: {"Third", "Fourth","Fifth"}},
{State: "NJ",
Type: {"Primary", "Third"}}]
```

What i am trying to do is orderby/display so that the first records are always which have primary, followed by secondary, Third, Fourth etc. The result from above data should be. The Primary, Secondary, Third etc are enum strings and are hard coded. Any pointers on how to achieve this in LINQ.

```
[{State: "PA",
Type: {"Primary","Secondary"}},
{State: "NJ",
Type: {"Primary", "Third"}}]
{State: "TX",
Type: {"Secondary", "Third"}},
{State: "NC",
Type: {"Third", "Fourth","Fifth"}}]
```

Comment: What is the data types/class definition?

Comment: Any pointers? First parse the enum strings back to the enum values and order by Min(type).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your custom type implements the interface IComparer. While doing so you will implement your own comparison logic. Once this is done you'll just have to call order by on your collection and this last would be sorted according to the custom logic you will provide in you IComparer implementation